# Ruby gem for reading/writing XLSX with support of named range

Tags: excel, ruby, rubygems, xlsx

Can you please suggest me a ruby gem for parsing and updating an XLSX file with support of Excel named ranges?

The only gem I found with an explicitly stated ability to work with named ranges is [OOXL](https://github.com/halcjames/ooxl). But it only reads XLSX files. Writing is not its option.

I need support of XLSX only (not XLS) for a Linux machine, without MS Excel installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this gem [axlsx](https://github.com/randym/axlsx), and check the examples [Examples](https://github.com/randym/axlsx/tree/master/examples)

Comment: Unfortunately, axlsx is a write-only solution. It can't read an XLSX file, assign a cell a new value and write the updated file.